# How to set menu time pop up time on exoplayer?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

With the Android Exoplayer, when you tap on the screen it brings up the seekbar and some custom buttons I've coded overlayed on top of the video. Is there an attribute to set for how long that menu stays on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below declared tag in xml.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/mPlayerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view"
                app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_simple_player_view"
                app:repeat_toggle_modes="none"
                app:resize_mode="fixed_height"

                app:show_timeout="5000"

                app:surface_type="texture_view" />
```

The attribute show_timeout when given in milliseconds as mentioned in above player will make the control disappear after 5 seconds. Check [this](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerControlView.html).

Hope it helps. Happy coding!